# MATLAB find on multiple columns to multiple column result

Tags: matlab, find, padding, coding-efficiency

### Setup

I have an array of captured data. The data may be captured on just 1 device or up to a dozen devices, with each device being a column in the array. I have a prior statement which I execute on the array to then turn it into a logical array to find particular points of interest in the data. Due to the nature of the data, there are many 0's and only a few 1's. I need to return an array with the indices of the 1's so I can go back and capture the data *between* those points (see update below).

`find` is an obvious choice for a function - however, the result I need, needs to have 1 column for each device. Normally `find` will do a linear index regardless of the dimensions of the array.

The devices follow a pattern - but aren't exactly the same. So, complicating this is the fact that the number of 1's in each column is close to, but not guaranteed to be exactly the same depending on the exact timing the data capture is stopped (they are most often different from each other by 1 element, but could be different by more).

### MATLAB CODE ATTEMPTS

Because of that difference, I can't use the following simple code:

```
for p = 1:np
    indices( :, p ) = find( device.data.cross( :, p ) );
end
```

Notes:

- `np` is the number of columns in the data = number of devices captured.
- `devices` is a `class` representing the collection of devices
- `data` is a `TimeTable` containing captured data on all the devices
- `cross` is a column in the `data` `TimeTable` which contains the logical array
- Even this simple code is inefficient and generates the Code Analyzer warning:

> The variable 'indices' appears to change size on every loop
> iteration (within a script). Consider preallocating for speed.

As expected, it doesn't work as I get an error similar to the following:

> Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is
> 448-by-1 and the size of the right side is 449-by-1.

I know why I get this error - each column in an array in MATLAB has to have the same number of rows, so I can't make the assignment if the row size doesn't match. I need to pad the "short" columns somehow. In this case, repeating the last index will work for my later operations without causing an error.

I can't figure out a "good" way to do this. I can't pre-populate the array rows because I don't know how many rows there will be until I've done the find operation.

I can change the code as follows:

```
    indices = [];
    for p = 1:np
        tempindices = find( devices.data.cross(:, p) );
        sizediff = size( tempindices, 1 ) - size( indices, 1 );
        
        if p > 1
            
            if sizediff > 0

                padding = repmat(indices(end, 1:(p - 1)), sizediff, 1);
                indices = [indices; padding];

            elseif sizediff < 0

                padding = repmat(tempindices(end), abs(sizediff), 1);
                tempindices = [tempindices; padding];

            end
            
        end

        indices(:,p) = tempindices;
        
    end
```

Note: `padarray` would have been useful here, but I don't have the `Image Processing Toolbox` so I cannot use it.

This code works, but it is very inefficient, it creates multiple otherwise unneeded variables in the workspace and generates multiple "appears to change size on every loop iteration" warnings in Code Analyzer. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

### Update / Additional Information:

Some more context is needed for my issue. Given that devices.data.cross is a logical array, to just "pick" the data I want from other columns in my table (as I originally described my problem) I could select a column from devices.data.cross and pass that logical column as a subscript to get that data. I do that where it works. However, for some of the columns I need to select "chunks" of the data between the indices and that's where (I think) I need the indices. Or, at least I don't know of another way to do it.

Here is example code of how I use the indices:

```
for p = 1:np
    for i = 2:num_indices

        these_indices = indices(i-1, p):( indices(i, p) - 1 );
        rmsvoltage = sqrt( mean( devices.data.voltage(these_indices).^2 ) );

    end

end
```

This is just one routine I do on the "chunks" of data. I also have a couple of functions where these chunks of data are passed for processing.

Comment: Do you really need an array of indices? What about the alternatives: 1) A cell-array containing per cell the indices for one row; or 2) A logical array of the same size as ```devices.data.cross``` indicating the interesting points or 3) Two vectors ```rows``` and ```cols``` giving the subscripts of interesting points in ```devices.data.cross```?

Comment: `[row,col] = find(___)` should work. Otherwise, `indices{p} = find( device.data.cross( :, p ) );`

Comment: @user16372530 I tried to simplify my example and not get too far into the weeds here. Note: as I stated in my question, devices.data.cross already is the logical array. I have 33 columns of data (4 of those columns contain columns within the columns). For those columns  where I just need to "pick" the data at those exact points, I do just pass one column from devices.data.cross into them and get that data. However, I use the indices when I have to grab "chunks" of data from the other columns - which is from indices(n-1):(indices(n)-1). Is there a way to do that with just a logical array?

Comment: @CrisLuengo thank you for the suggestions. At the moment, I don't see how [row, col] would work for my situation (see the additional information I added). I'm running out of time to work on this today, but your cell notation might work, I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: I found a solution. I was able to use `[Indices, Columns] = find( cross )` suggested by both of you (I didn't use the name "rows" because I didn't want these rows confused with the rows of the resulting array) Then I could loop through each column (which is a max of 12 loops), check the number of indices associated with each column, get the max then use that number and the number of columns as the dimensions to pre-allocate my cell array using the `cell` function, then populate each element in the for loops with each "chunk" without growing the dimensions each loop.

Answer (score 0):

When I understood your problem correctly, the code below should work. I'm using the approach that Cris Luengo suggested in a comment under your question.

Key element is `[rowIdcs, colIdcs] = find( cros );` which gives you the subscripts of positions in `cros` having a value of one. Please find further comments inline.

```
% Create some data for testing
volt = randn(10,10);
cros = randi(10,10,10) > 9;

% Get rowIdcs and colIdcs, which have both a size of Nx1, 
% with N denoting the number of ones in the mask.
% rowIdcs and colIdcs are the subscripts of the ones in the mask.
[rowIdcs, colIdcs] = find( cros );

% The number of chunks is equal to number N of ones found in the mask;
numChunks = numel( rowIdcs ); 

% Initilize a vector for the rms
rms = zeros( numChunks, 1 );

% Loop over the chunks
for k = 1 : numChunks
   
    curRow = rowIdcs(k);
    curCol = colIdcs(k);
    
    % Get indices of range over neighbouring rows
    chunkRowIdcs = curRow + [-1 0 1]; %i.e. these_indices in your example
    
    % Remove indices that are out of range
    chunkRowIdcs( chunkRowIdcs < 1 | chunkRowIdcs > size(volt,1) ) = [];
    
    % Get voltages covered by chunk 
    chunkVoltages = volt( chunkRowIdcs, curCol );
    
    % Get RMS over voltages
    rms(k) = sqrt( mean( chunkVoltages(:).^2 ));
    
end
```

Comment: This is a good piece of code but unfortunately, it doesn't actually do what I want for multiple reasons. If you look at my RMS calculation above and yours, you can see they don't do the same thing. Also, I need the full set of indices out in the end so I can pass them to functions other than just my RMS function. This does illustrate how to use [row col] = find ( ) though and that was helpful in solving my problem.. Thank You.